# [Android]-Cannot play m3u8 when network changes

Tags: android, video, stream, m3u8, vitamio

I'm an Android developer. I have a question, hope everyone helps me.
I try to play m3u8 from this website: https://fptplay.net/livetv/vtv1-hd.
This is my code:

```
 private void initPlayer(){
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_channel);
    //fvideoView.show
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlVideo));
    videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
     mc =  new MediaController(PlayTiviActivity.this);

    mc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);

    prbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
            prbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

I added user-permission in Mainifest: 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

I get link m3u8 from this website and I can play it well in iOS, but when I play it in Android, I rarely can play it. It show message "Cannot play this video". Sometimes, I can play it by 3G network. Somtimes it shows me that message.Some days before I can play it well with this code. I really don't understand why? I try to use Vitamio library, ExoLibrary library but it also fail.
Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you initiate the Vitamio before playing?

Comment: Thank for your replying. I solved the problem.

Comment: This website use IP from client to create a token. I find the way to get this m3u8 link.